# Caching firebase data not to make duplicate requests. Angular2 with angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-routing, angularfire2

I'm getting an observable list of objects from firebase, then subscribe to it (via async pipe) in my component. For now everything works perfect. List is only reloaded when something changes.

```js
//getting observable list from firebase
//ArticlesService
    public getAllArticles(limit:number = 100):Observable<Article[]>
     {
        return this.af.database.list("/articles/", {
          query: {
            limitToFirst: limit
          }
        }).map( (arts) => {
          return arts.map(art => {
            return Article.unpack(art); //creating an Article object
          })
        })
     }
```

```js
//ArticlesComponent
ngOnInit() {
    this.articles$ = this.artService.getAllArticles();
 }
```

```html
<app-articles-list [articles]="articles$ | async"></app-articles-list>
```

However, when I use Angular2 router and navigate out from the route and then back - seems like all the same data is loaded once again from the firebase which creates a rendering delay and traffic overhead.

I guess it happens because when I navigate out and then back, subscription is recreated and data is asked like if it wasn't already loaded.

So, I was thinking what would be the way to avoid such behaviour? Could be caching, could be something else. Not really sure at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! This article helped a lot: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0

```js
//ArticleService
private allArticles$:Observable<Article[]>; 

public getAllArticles(limit:number = 100):Observable<Article[]>
  {
    if(!this.allArticles$)
    {
      this.allArticles$ = this.af.database.list("/articles/", {
        query: {
          limitToFirst: limit
        }
      }).map( (arts) => {


        return arts.map(art => {
          let unpacked = Article.unpack(art);
          return unpacked;
        })
      }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
    //for all new subscriptions replay emitted values
    }
    return this.allArticles$;
  }
```